# How to create a Python tkinter Frame with button-like functionality?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am looking to create a tile in tkinter that will have text in each of the corners, similar to this image:

```
 _______
|a     b|
|c_____d|
```

I also want it to have the functionality of when it is clicked, to run a command function. My current idea is to create a frame which can hold four text labels, then allow that frame to be clicked.

```
import tkinter as tk
newFrame = tk.Frame()
newFrame.grid(row=0,column=0)

tk.Label(newFrame, text="a").grid(row=0,column=0)
tk.Label(newFrame, text="b").grid(row=0,column=1)
tk.Label(newFrame, text="c").grid(row=1,column=0)
tk.Label(newFrame, text="d").grid(row=1,column=1)

newFrame.config(command = makeFruity)
```

Obviously, the last line doesn't work. And after searching online and reading documentation, I still have absolutely no idea how to then get that frame to hold a command. And so, I am reaching out to the experts, if anyone could help I would be very thankful!

Comment: Use `place` method (don't mix with other).

Comment: Thanks for your comment dsgdfg, but I'm a bit confused, what should I .place()? The Frame? The Labels? Could you please post an example? Many thanks.

Comment: How much of a button functionality do you mean? Does it need to get pushed in and back out for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `bind("<Button-1>", callback)` to assign click to widgets.

You may have to bind not only to `Frame` but also `Labels`.

```
import tkinter as tk

def makeFruity(event):
    print('makeFruity')
    print('event:', event)
    print('event.widget:', event.widget)
    try:
        print('event.widget.text:', event.widget.cget('text'))
    except Exception as ex:
        print('error:', ex)

root = tk.Tk()

newFrame = tk.Frame(root)
newFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)

# resize middle row and column
newFrame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1, minsize=100)
newFrame.rowconfigure(1, weight=1, minsize=100)

# use row/column 2 instead of 1
l1 = tk.Label(newFrame, text="a")
l1.grid(row=0,column=0)

l2 = tk.Label(newFrame, text="b")
l2.grid(row=0,column=2)

l3 = tk.Label(newFrame, text="c")
l3.grid(row=2,column=0)

l4 = tk.Label(newFrame, text="d")
l4.grid(row=2,column=2)

l1.bind('<Button-1>', makeFruity)
l2.bind('<Button-1>', makeFruity)
l3.bind('<Button-1>', makeFruity)
l4.bind('<Button-1>', makeFruity)

newFrame.bind('<Button-1>', makeFruity)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400+50+50")
elements = {}
def getElemVarName(name):
    print "You clicked :%s element in ELEMENTS dict" %name

def Move(e):
    key = e.keysym
    for i in elements.keys() :
        X,Y= int(elements[i].place_info()["x"]),int(elements[i].place_info()["y"])
        if key == "Up" :
            elements[i].place_configure(x=X, y=Y-1 )
        elif key == "Down" :
            elements[i].place_configure(x=X, y=Y+1 )
        elif key == "Left" :
            elements[i].place_configure(x=X-1, y=Y)
        elif key == "Right" :
            elements[i].place_configure(x=X+1, y=Y)

        elements[i].config(text="%d-%d"%(X,Y))

for i in range(4):
    pos = divmod(i,2)
    lb = Label(root,text=str(i))
    lb.place(x=pos[1]*50+10,y=(pos[0]*50)+10)
    elements["%d"%i] = lb

for eve in ('<Left>','<Right>','<Up>','<Down>') :
    root.bind(eve, Move)
for i in elements.keys() :
    elements[i].bind('<Button-1>', lambda event,s=i:getElemVarName(s))
root.mainloop()
```

So : 
`for i in range(4):`  for 4 elements

`pos = divmod(i,2)` set Grid value

`lb = Label(root)` Create label

`lb.place(x=pos[1]*50+10,y=(pos[0]*50)+10)` 
Mean : `pos[1]*50+10` ; `pos[1]` XGrid_Position , `*50` xGrid_Size, `+10` Offset(same pattern on `y` value)

**If you change the item text, you cannot search by text.**

Push keyboard arrow key for what happening.(PY2.7) **Use only one positioning method(pack,grid,place)** (if you thing complex GUI ,The method of the `place` can fulfill the functions of other methods.)

After Comment :
`elements[i].bind('<Button-1>', lambda event,s=i:getElemVarName(s))` Use **lambda** function for passed variable name as string!

Comment: main problem is how to click. And you donn't describe this problem.

Comment: i think no, is very clear ! I added "how" section. The language may be important to you, but for me the character is more important. I don't think the answer you typed has anything to do with the question.

Comment: question is `... with button-like functionality` and OP write that `command=` doesn't work so `<Button-1>` is more imortant part, as for me.

Comment: Thank you for writing out your answer and giving me your time.